# jQuery animation big images not very smooth

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I wrote [this(jsfiddler)](http://jsfiddle.net/RT96d/) plugin that creates a slideshow. It works okay but the problem is that I have to use it for big background images. In Chrome it's nice and smooth but in IE and FF the transitions are really clunky and laggy.

At the following link you can find an example that's very slow in the browsers mentioned.

http://www.friendly-stranger.com/projects/kick/

The images them self are a little optimized to around 180kb.

Answer (score 0):

You may be overthinking this. Why use jQuery to create an image slideshow for the background images? Why not just create an animated GIF and set it as the background of your body tag? That way, the only overhead you have is the downloading of the image.

Comment: No, i think you are under thinking it. What if he wanted to add an image to it? He would have to remake the gif.

Comment: @invisible bob - That is true. However, if you setup your GIF correctly (and have half-decent software), it's extremely simple to add another image (or remove an image) and push out the new GIF. So, this is definitely a viable solution (this is assuming, of course, that a GIF format is acceptable to him).

Comment: Like invisible bob says the client adds images to the cms. Also my example should lazy load the images I am not sure how it would work with gifs and third ain't gifs limited in colour?

Comment: @Pickels - Ah, okay. I did not realize the client was adding the image. And, yes, GIFs are limited in color. Not always a problem, but it sounds like it is in this case (which is why I said GIF needed to be acceptable for your use).

Answer (score 0):

They both worked for me, just make sure the function waits until the images are loaded to run (jsfiddle does this automatically). I would recommend having the div start hidden, and when it is done loading, appear. it hides the lag (if there is any). http://jsfiddle.net/RT96d/3/

Comment: Thanks, I knew they worked but in FF and IE the image stutters when fading in.